# a simple string substitution does not work

Tags: string, perl, substitution

Below is my codes:

```
my $string1 = '<td><a href="http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>';
my $string2 = 'http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3';


print "Before string substitution:\n$string1\n";
$string1 =~ s/$string2//;
print "After string substitution:\n$string1\n";
```

And the actual output:

```
Before string substitution:
<td><a href="http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
After string substitution:
<td><a href="http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
```

What I expect:

```
Before string substitution:
<td><a href="http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
After string substitution:
<td><a href="">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
```

could someone please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML and regexes, a fatal attraction.

Comment: @MkV you mean *addiction*?

Answer (score 2):

That problem can be fixed by adding two characters to your script. What you need is to escape meta characters in `$string2`:

```
$string1 =~ s/\Q$string2//;
```

The character that causes the match to fail is the question mark `?`, which unescaped here `...aspx?...` means "match 0 or 1 of the character 'x'". The characters `.` are wildcards that match anything except newline, which may cause false positive matches. The slashes `/`, while being meta characters due to being the delimiter of the substitution operator `s///`, do not need to be escaped since they are embedded in a string.

Escaping meta characters is most easily done with the `\Q ... \E` escape sequence, inside a regex, or with `quotemeta`.

It is not a good idea to try and escape these kinds of strings manually, especially if literal matches are all that is required.

Comment: `?` is the only character that prevents it from matching. The two `.` could also become *troublesome*.

Comment: @BradGilbert I am not sure what your message is with this comment.

Comment: If you only fixed the `?`. It could still match `http://www_aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3` (swap the first `.` for `_`). Which would make the first `.`  a problem. ( The comment was mostly for future viewers of this answer )

Comment: @brad The solution I presented does not present a problem with meta characters.

Comment: I know it doesn't. If someone who had a similar problem just backslashed the `?`, they could still have a problem. One which is far harder to find. I figured there should be something that pointed out that using `quotemeta` and `\Q ... \E` would fix other problems that weren't yet apparent.

Comment: @BradGilbert Perhaps it is now phrased more completely.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting in characters that are considered special characters by perl regex, you must escape them out like this:

```
my $string2 = 'http:\/\/www\.aaa\.com\/downloads\/details\.aspx\?FamilyID=a1b2c3';
```

Then the expected output will show up when you run your program:

```
<td><a href="http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
After string substitution:
<td><a href="">abcdefg</a><br />(123456)</td>
```

To escape these characters from your string, it is best to just use perl's [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function:

```
my $string2 = quotemeta('http://www.aaa.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a1b2c3');
```

This will escape the special characters for you and then your regex replace will work fine.

**EDIT**

Since you're having issues because of non-escaped regex characters, this solution might be simpler since it does not require you to escape any characters:

```
substr($string1, index($string1,$string2), length($string2)) = '';
```

This is based off of this example:

```
my $name = 'fred';
substr($name, 4) = 'dy'; # $name is now 'freddy'
```

found in the perldocs for [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

Comment: You're definitely on the right track; the primary trouble-maker is the `?`; the slashes actually aren't a problem in this context (put a backslash in front of the `?` only, and try it).  The `.` characters will match the `.` quite happily (as well as anything else).  De facto, it is unlikely that a string will cause problems because of the dots.

Comment: Your [`substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr "perldoc -f substr") example should almost be `{my $index=index($string1,$string2);if($index >= $[){substr($string1,$index,length($string2),'')}}`. What you have now appends the empty string to the end of `$string1` if it doesn't match. Right now it isn't much of a problem, but in the future it could cause an unnecessary copy when [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) strings become the default.